# How do i create a counter in c?

Tags: c

Im trying to write a code that can tell the difference between an even number and odd number. Even numbers need to be added while the Odd numbers need to have a counter. Any way to fix what i tried?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i;
int number;
int Odd = 0;
int Even = 0;

printf("Please enter 10 integers:");
for(i=0; i<=10; i++)

    scanf("%d", &number);
    if(number % 2 == 0){
       Even = number + 1;
    }
    else{
        Odd =  number + 1;
    }
printf("Even number sum = %d\n", Even);
printf("Odd number counter = %d\n", Odd);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re “Any way to fix what i tried?”: What do you think is wrong with what you tried?

Comment: `sum_of_evens = sum_of_evens + number;`  aka `sum_of_evens += number;` // `count_of_odds = count_of_odds + 1;` aka `count_of_odds += 1;`, aka `++count_of_odds;`

Comment: you're saying you want to count all the odd numbers and sum all the even numbers?

Comment: Yes thats exactly my question. Sorry for bad phrasing

Comment: This `Even = number + 1` doesn't seem to do either of the two operations you describe.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<=10; i++)` This will run for `i` in the range from `0` to `10` which is 11 numbers. You probably wanted `for(i=0; i<10; i++)`

Answer (score 3):

As the comments on your post describe, your `Even = number + 1` is not doing much.

If i understood correctly, you want all even numbers to be added and count how many odd numbers have been introduced. You could acomplish this by simply changing your if from:

```
if(number % 2 == 0){
   Even = number + 1;
}
else{
    Odd =  number + 1;
}
```

to

```
if(number % 2 == 0){
   Even = Even + number;
}
else{
    Odd =  Odd + 1;
}
```

Needless to say it can be simplified to `Even += number;` and `Odd++;`

Comment: `Even += number` and `Odd++` it is a bit more "C style"

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple things wrong with your code.

As others have already mentioned your logic for adding the Even numbers and counting Odds is wrong.

Also, you need to add braces to your for loop like so:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if(number % 2 == 0)
    {
       Even = Even + number;
    }
    else
    {
        Odd = Odd + 1;
    }
}
```